# 'Queueing' tutorials and documentation?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery, task-queue, kombu

I'm looking for articles and references that give an overview of 'queueing' (I'm probably not even using the right term here). I'm hoping for an introductory styled guide through a world of Redis, RabbitMQ, Celery, Kombu, and whatever other components exist that I haven't read about yet, and how they fit together.

My problem is I need to queue up background tasks for issued by my Django website, and every blog and article I read recommend different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options available to you, and your choice will likely come down to personal preference and what dependencies you feel comfortable installing.

I'll give a vote for Redis.  I evaluated RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, HornetQ, and Redis and found Redis to offer the best mix of ease of installation, simplicity, and performance.

It's technically not a message queue, but the push/pop primitives for the list types provide atomic queue-like operations, so it can effectively be used as a queue.  It has worked well for us.

One python specific project on top of Redis you might look at:

http://richardhenry.github.com/hotqueue/tutorial.html

Very simple.  But again, all the other options, like Celery, are viable too.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ has a good introduction here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html There's examples in Python, even.

Answer (score 0):

HornetQ has a very good documentation, and it's simple to install.

You can find the documentation at [www.hornetq.org](http://www.hornetq.org), and you would have several examples available with the distribution.